# JAX-WS Endpoint not working

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, jax-ws

I'm writing a (very) small SOAP web service using Glassfish.  The code I have is below:

**Milliseconds.java**

```
package com.suture.self.ws;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Use;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT, use = Use.LITERAL)
public interface Milliseconds {
    @WebMethod
    String currentMilliseconds();
}
```

**MillisecondsImpl.java**

```
package com.suture.self.ws;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.suture.self.ws.Milliseconds") 
public class MillisecondsImpl implements Milliseconds {

    @Override
    public String currentMilliseconds() {
        return String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

**MillisecondsEndpoint.java**

```
package com.suture.self.ws;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class MillisecondsEndpoint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://sutureself.com:9292/ws/milli", new MillisecondsImpl());
    }
}
```

When I run this on my Glassfish server (through Eclipse), the admin console shows me the usual working `?wsdl` and `?Tester` endpoints, but not the one I have created. Hitting that url (http://sutureself.com:9292/ws/milli) in a browser also returns an "Unable to connect" error.

If I select "Launch", then I am shown two links (one for each http port in Glassfish), but these return a 404.

If I just try to hit the "Context Root" path, that also doesn't work.  I need a point of entry and I just cannot find it.

What am I missing?

Please note! All the `sutureself.com`'s in the above code are actually `localhost`, SO doesn't like you posting URL's with localhost evidently.

Any more information as to how my setup is configured will happily be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also did an example in SOAP WS some time before but I have one doubt, why are you using **Glassfish Server** because you are deploying your WS by main method which will bind the address with your Service. I think for that no server is required.

Just follow these steps with eclipse for testing the WS-

**Note: Please shutdown your Glassfish Server**

1-Create a new java project(not dynamic web project)

2-Create a *HelloWorld* class in *hello* package

```
package hello;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class HelloWorld{
    @WebMethod
    public String method(String name)
    {

        return "hello " +name;
    }
}
```

you don't need to make interface explicitly.

3:Now  create a *Publisher* class to publish the WebService in *hello* package

```
package hello;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class Publisher {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Endpoint.publish("http://LH.com:9292/ws/milli", new HelloWorld());
    }

}
```

Now you have bound your WS with http://LH.com:9292/ws/milli. Check it by http://LH.com:9292/ws/milli?wsdl or http://LH.com:9292/ws/milli?test

Comment: Tried changing it to 9091 (which is definitely free) and still get the same thing, "Unable to connect".

Comment: @SutureSelf check edited answer. Hope this will be helpful. lh.com=localhost

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update.  When you say "no server is required", do I just create a JAR (or WAR?) of this package and run it, or do I still need to deploy it in Tomcat or Glassfish?  Sorry, new to writing web services.

Comment: @SutureSelf you have to just run the publisher class because it has main method or you can make a runnable jar for it.

Comment: No need of deployment, just run it as simple java program.